# SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR when connecting to APNS

Tags: python, django

My servers APNS notifications recently stopped working and after debugging I found that the SSL python library is throwing the following error when opening a socket:

```
  File "/home/tam/repos/rest/api/tasks/notification_tasks.py", line 17, in apns_socket
self._apns_socket = apns.open_apns_socket()
  File "/home/tam/repos/rest/api/utilities/apns.py", line 64, in open_apns_socket
return _apns_create_socket((settings.APNS_HOST, settings.APNS_PORT))
  File "/home/tam/repos/rest/api/utilities/apns.py", line 49, in _apns_create_socket
sock.connect(address_tuple)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 1014, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 1005, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:645)
```

Nothing has changed on the server codewise. I've checked APNS certificates (they haven't expired), and our SSL certificate (also not expired). I'm unsure what else could be causing this error at this point.

Here are the relavent lines of code from apns.py:

```
def open_apns_socket():
    return _apns_create_socket((settings.APNS_HOST, settings.APNS_PORT))

def _apns_create_socket(address_tuple, is_dev=False):
    certfile = settings.APS_CERTIFICATE
    if not certfile:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('You need to set settings.APNS_CERTIFICATE')

    try:
        with open(certfile, "r") as f:
            f.read()
    except Exception as e:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The APNS certificate file at %r is not readable: %s" % (certfile, e))

    ca_certs = settings.APNS_CA_CERTIFICATES

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, certfile=certfile, ca_certs=ca_certs)
    sock.connect(address_tuple)

    return sock
```

APNS_HOST = "gateway.push.apple.com"

APNS_PORT = 2195

Comment: fwiw, [fastly dropped tls<1.2 recently](https://www.fastly.com/blog/phase-two-our-tls-10-and-11-deprecation-plan) perhaps your `APNS_HOST` is fronted by fastly?  Perhaps try `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` instead?

Comment: it's a great idea, but no luck. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This error turned out to be caused by an expired apns certificate on the server.

The server certificate was different from what was in our version control and was not being updated by our deployment software.

Issuing a new certificate solved the problem.